# To what grammar does "etw ist auf ... zurückzuführen" belong?

Tags: grammar-identification

I am unable to identify this usage as either Perfekt or Passiv or Infinitiv usage. Should this be categorized as a "fixed phrase"?

> etw ist auf ... zurückzuführen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the combination *sein* + *zu*-infinitive, *sein* is an *infinitregierendes Modalitätsverb*. It's not a fixed phrase, but a productive pattern.

Other verbs of these class are *haben*, *scheinen* and *drohen* if they appear with a *zu*-infinitive:

> - Das ist darauf zurückzuführen.
> - Die Niederlage hat der Trainer zu verantworten.
> - Die Begrüßung scheint hier Brauch zu sein.
> - Dieses Ereignis droht in Vergessenheit zu geraten.

*Ist* + *zu*-infinitive is special because it corresponds to a passive construction, while the other ones work like a active verb.

While *scheinen* and *drohen* have a rather specific meaning in that context, *sein* + *zu*-infinitive can express different modalities:

> - Das ist anzunehmen. ('That *can/must* be assumed.' ~ 'Probably')
> - Reden ist zu unterlassen! ('Talking *must* be forbeared!' ~ 'Stop talking!')
> - Das ist nicht zu unterschätzen. ('That *may not* be underestimated.')
> - Das ist nicht zu glauben. ('That *can't* be believed.' ~ 'That's unbelievable.').

Comment: Infinitregierendes Modalitätsverb: https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Modalitatsverben

Answer (score 1):

This is not a "fixed phrase" - but a "fixed form"

> etwas ist auf etwas zurückzuführen
> etwas ist anzunehmen
> etwas ist nachzuweisen

This form is called a *Infinitiv Aktiv*, here forming a construct similar to the Latin *Gerundivum*, in your example of the verb "zurückführen". It expresses modality as in "can", "must", "should".

English uses a similar fixed form with "to be to", expressing "must"

> The defendant is to be punished

> der Angeklagte ist zu bestrafen

Comment: Also called an "extended infinitive", "erweiterter Infinitiv": https://www.wortbedeutung.info/zur%C3%BCckzuf%C3%BChren/